# When is non-volatile field write to main memory

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Because the `done` is non-volatile, so I will expect thread 1 will keep executing and printing out "Done".

But when I run the program, here is the output from console

```
Done
Undo
```

*This means that thread 2's update is seen by thread 1, right? (But `done` isn't a volatile field.)*.

My explanation is that thread 1 and thread 2 are running in the same core. So that they can see update of the filed, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Overall, my question is why thread 1 can see the change of thread 2? Is this related to CPU cache write back/through to main memory? If it is, when does it happen?

```java
public class Done {

    boolean done = true;

    public void m1() throws InterruptedException {
        while (this.done) {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        System.out.println("Undo");
    }

    public void undo() {
        done = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Done v = new Done();
        es.submit(() -> {
            try {
                v.m1();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }); // thread 1

        es.submit(() -> {
            v.undo();
        }); // thread 2

        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Visibility is not guaranteed, but it is still possible.  That's the problem with non-synchonized programs: their  output is unpredictable.  There's very little useful results you can get from a program that is not correctly synchronized.

Comment: `My explanation is that thread 1 and thread 2 are running in the same core.` You're probably running on Intel hardware.  Intel's caches are coherent, meaning updates are visible even to other cores.  Thus, Intel hardware provides a stronger guarantee of visibility than Java does.  Why?  I think it's because Java was designed to be portable, and its designers wanted the option of running on hardware that wasn't fully cache-coherent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)'s guarantees work in only one way. If something is guaranteed, like the visibility of a volatile write, then it'll work 100% of the time.

If there's no guarantee, it doesn't mean it'll never happen. Sometimes non-volatile writes will be seen by other threads. If you run this code many times on different machines with different JVMs, you'll probably see different results.